# Is it possible to redirect in Gollum wiki (GitHub wiki) pages?

Tags: github, wiki, gollum-wiki

At RailsConf 2012, our local Ruby group created a [crowd-sourced wiki](https://github.com/newhavenrb/railsconf2012/wiki).  We're very happy with how well it was received (218 watchers as of today).

Some members are attending Goruco 2012, and we'd like to do something similar for that conference.  The current plan is to have one big git-based wiki of Ruby conferences.  We have content for the last couple of years (RubyConf 2011, RailsConf 2011, 2012, and now Goruco 2012), so we'd like to combine it into one place.  The RailsConf 2012 wiki has gotten the most watchers by far, and we'd like to retain those.  The simplest way would seem to be renaming the repository like so:

- Old: https://github.com/newhavenrb/railsconf2012/wiki
- New: https://github.com/newhavenrb/conferences/wiki

The "Home" page would then have a listing of conferences by year.

But because it's become a community resource, we don't want to break any links from blogs, Twitter, etc.  What's the easiest way of doing this?  Does [Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum) support any kind of redirect?  (Or do we need to come up with a creative solution?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since no one has come out of the woodwork, here's what I'm planning to do:

- Clone the existing wiki
- Run script

```bash
for f in *.md; do
  cat <<EOF > $f
We've Moved!
------------

The RailsConf 2012 wiki is now [a general Ruby conference wiki](https://github.com/newhavenrb/conferences/wiki).

Please find this page in its new home:  https://github.com/newhavenrb/conferences/wiki/$(basename $f .md)
EOF
done
```

That would make Markdown like this:

> ### We've Moved!
>
> The RailsConf 2012 wiki is now [a general Ruby conference wiki](https://github.com/newhavenrb/conferences/wiki).
>
> Please find this page in its new home:  https://github.com/newhavenrb/conferences/wiki/Rich-Hickey-Keynote

- Commit the changes (except `Home.md`, `README.md`, `_Footer.md`, `_Sidebar.md`; they would be wrong)
- Rename the existing wiki to `conferences`
- Make new repo named `railsconf2012`
- Push "We've Moved!" content to the new `railsconf2012` repo

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems to take GitHub a while to rename a wiki with many forks, etc.  I tested this on a new wiki and it worked immediately, but I'm just waiting to finish the above steps right now.  (GitHub says "Name already exists on this account")

Comment: GitHub never stopped saying "Name already exists on this account".  (Maybe a bug?)  My workaround:  make a new repo called "tmpwiki", rename it from "tmpwiki" to "railsconf2012", push content as described before.

Comment: I made this into a script: [`add-redirect-links`](https://github.com/newhavenrb/conferences/blob/master/script/add-redirect-links).