# How to redirect to another wiki page in GitHub flavored Markdown?

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

I would like to create alias pages on GitHub Wiki. Is there something similar to a Wikipedia feature that redirects [WP:R](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:R) and [WP:RDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:RDR) to [Wikipedia:Redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Redirect) page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitHub removed/never added the possibility to configure redirects.

The original Gollum wiki supports redirects:
https://github.com/gollum/gollum/wiki#redirects

But, as I tested right now, GitHub disabled the feature. It doesn't even work with renamed pages, sorry.

You can see here: [Is it possible to redirect in Gollum wiki (GitHub wiki) pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138802/is-it-possible-to-redirect-in-gollum-wiki-github-wiki-pages) how people solved the same issue 9 years ago...